# Como deletar todas os registros de um belongsToMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

No laravel, quando temos um relacionamento muitos para muitos, temos um método chamado `attach` e `detach`

O `attach` adiciona entrada num relacionamento `n:n`, e o `detach` as remove.

Nos dois casos, essas operações são realizadas quando se passa um array como parâmetro

Assim:

```
class Action extends Eloquent{

   public function roles()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'roles_actions');
   }
}


class Role extends Eloquent{

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Action', 'roles_actions');
    }
}
```

Aí, quando quero deletar entradas desse relacionamento, faço:

```
$role = Role::find(1);

$role->actions()->detach([1, 2, 3])
// DELETE FROM roles_actions WHERE action_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND role_id = 1
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para deletar todas as entradas dessa tabela de relacionamento (sem ter que especificar um por um para fazer isso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para excluir todas os relacionamentos, basta executar o método `detach()` sem nenhum parâmetro:

```
$role = Role::find(1);

$role->actions()->detach();
```

Comment: Valeu, @gmsantos. Deu certinho aqui.